# Where to put resources?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I need to add some properties file to my application. I have added this file to `controller` directory, but can't load them (no in classpath ?) - `InputStream` is null. Where to put this file to can be accessed ?

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    static {
        try {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            InputStream in =  Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("accounts.properties");
            if(in != null) {
                p.load(in);
                in.close();
            } else {
                error("null inputstream");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    // Actions below 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to put it in the `conf` folder of your Play app.

You can also use subfolder in the `conf` directory.

For instance:

```
conf/foo/bar.txt
```

can be accessed using:

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class. getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar.txt")
```

You can also add a custom resources directory in your app, by updating your `project/Build.scala` file and adding:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      ...
      resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory / "myresources"
      ...
  )
```

Comment: With newer versions of `sbt`, you would write: `resourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "myresources"`