# Scala Play - reading in a text file

Tags: scala, playframework

I've been running a play app locally using `sbt run` that reads a text file from the conf directory using

```
Source.fromFile("conf/colorMappings.txt").readLines()
```

When I package the application into a zip file using `sbt dist` the file is not found. I have tried adding a setting to build.sbt:

```
resourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "conf"
```

and using

```
Source.fromInputStream(CategoryServiceImpl.this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("colorMappings.txt"))
```

which doesn't work for sbt run, let alone sbt dist. How do I package a text file and read it in?

I've looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989510/where-to-put-resources), and it doesn't seem to work with Play 2.5

Comment: have you tried /src/main/resources?

Comment: Ya still doesn't work

Comment: Not understanding why. Have you tried the same approach on a 2.4.x app?

Comment: Usually resource files are included in the jars by default. Give this a try: `Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/conf/colorMappings.txt"))` The difference is that there's a preceding slash `/conf` that tells it to look at the root of resource directory.